# Refresh Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive that use the service "**BoxService**" to take a certain value.

```
angular.module("App").directive('boxedWidget',
   function () {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
            scope: {       
            'source': '=',    
            },
          replace:true,
          templateUrl: '/widgets/box/widget.html',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              scope.item = scope.source;
               boxService
                .getBoxeValue(scope.item.id)
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                     scope.item.value = data;
                });

           }


        }

    });
```

Now I want to refresh the value every 5-seconds.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `$interval` to reload your data in Directive

```
$interval(function () {
loadData();
}, duration)
```

For more details of `$interval` you can refer to [Angular $interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Comment: i have just tried with       `setInterval(scope.changeValue(),5000);`

Comment: it's not the same. `$interval` cause refresh the `scope`. `setInterval` not.

Comment: yes @user5917414 ... Mosh Feu is Right this is very basic but very important difference.

Comment: @user5917414 Also you called `setInterval` wrong. That is unless `scope.changeValue` returns a function. `setInterval` and `$interval` require a function to call every period of time. Your calling `changeValue` once and passing the result into `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

did you inject $interval properly ?

```
  angular.module("App").directive('boxedWidget', ['$interval', function($interval) {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
            scope: {       
            'source': '=',    
            },
          replace:true,
          templateUrl: '/widgets/box/widget.html',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              scope.item = scope.source;
              // don't forget to inject $interval in the directive declaration
              $interval(function(){
                   boxService
                    .getBoxeValue(scope.item.id)
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                         scope.item.value = data;
                    });
              }, 5000);
           }


        }

    });
```